How to move a device from "usb controller" to "ports (com & LPT)"
I have a windows 10 laptop, I am trying to send information to a emco compact 5 CNC lathe.
The lathe itself has an RS-232 cable. I have bought an rs-232 to usb adapter from startech, but when I have plugged it in to the laptop it comes under "universal serial bus controllers" and is named "No printer attached" it also have no drivers installed.
I have installed the prolific Pl2305 from the manufacturer's website, but it still won't install on to the device
Q1 How do I install it?
Q2 Will this then move it in to ports (comp & lpt) so I can set up the bit rate and etc?

I you sure this is RS-232, which is serial. In your question, you refer to LPT, which is parallel and uses the same DB25 type connection. Quick internet search found this document. I don't know if this is right for your machine. If it is, then note on page 7, there is mention of needing a parallel interface. This is no mention of needing a seral interface.

IF this is about USB to RS232...
Such devices may have a "Enable Virtual COM-port" in the device settings.
Have a look around in the Device manager settings for the device/driver.
It was a long time since i last had to poke about in there;
SO the above might be wrong in some ways; no Windows available

I had downloaded loaded a virtual com port driver which did contact with the machine but the virtual driver wouldn't let me change the bit rate so it didn't connect properly

The login might need to be an Admin(?)
